# Scala error modeling

Tags: scala, error-handling

I am having my mind stuck on how to model error handling in the following case:

I have `CommonErrors` which are errors that can occur for all my methods

I also have specific errors such as: `Error1`, `Error2`, `Error3`

So we have in the end

`DoAErrors` = `CommonErrors` + `Error1` + `Error2`

`DoBErrors` = `CommonErrors` + `Error2` + `Error3`

and the method signatures :

```
doA() Either[DoAErrors, DoAResult]
doB() Either[DoBErrors, DoBResult]
```

To be nice I would like to use sealed traits so the clients of my library can safely pattern match on `DoAErrors` and `DoBErrors` and catch the common + specifics errors. So far what I tried :

```
sealed trait CommonErrors
… extends CommonErrors
… extends CommonErrors

sealed trait DoAErrors extends CommonErrors
Error1 extends DoAErrors

sealed trait DoBErrors extends CommonErrors

Error2 extends DoAErrors with DoBErrors
Error3 extends DoBErrors
```

The problem comes from the fact that `doA()` and `doB()` internally call a method that returns a `CommonError` and it is not possible to retrofit `CommonErrors` in `DoA` nor `DoB` errors. How would one model this case?

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like `CommonErrors` is actually one possible type of both `DoAErrors` and `DoBErrors`. In other words - the following statements are true:

> CommonErrors IS A DoAErrors
>
> CommonErrors IS A DoBErrors

This usually means that `CommonErrors` should extend the other types and not vice versa.

And indeed - the following code compiles and allows easy pattern-matching for call sites of `doA` and `doB`:

```
sealed trait DoAErrors
sealed trait DoBErrors
sealed trait CommonErrors extends DoAErrors with DoBErrors

class CommonE1 extends CommonErrors
class CommonE2 extends CommonErrors
class Error1 extends DoAErrors
class Error2 extends DoAErrors with DoBErrors
class Error3 extends DoBErrors

object Test {

  private def common(): Either[CommonErrors, String] = Left(new CommonE1())
  def doA(): Either[DoAErrors, String] = common()
  def doB(): Either[DoBErrors, String] = common()
}
```

Comment: hmm actually it makes sense, I will try and let you know. Originally I had only CommonErrors so when I added ErrorA and B I tried to compose with the existing errors. Thanks a lot !